# How can I remove text after clicking?

Tags: c, winapi

I'm making the prototype for my own visual novel game engine.

```
while (i < 5)
{
    switch (iMessage)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        //InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
        HDC hdc;
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"Korean");
        ReadScn(buf);
        //MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, char, strlen(buf), buf3, 256);
        CharToWChar(buf, buf2);
        TextOut(hdc, 320, 300, buf2, lstrlen(buf2)); //읽어들여서 출력함.
        //TCHAR*str = TEXT("beautiful korea");
        //TextOut(hdc, 320, 240, str, lstrlen(str));
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
        i++;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I wrote 5 lines of text to `scn.txt`. Then the program prints the texts to a window, but the text lines are overlapped.

How can I remove the previous text after clicking and print new text line?

Comment: Use `ExtTextOut` with `ETO_OPAQUE` is one way.

Comment: You can't have a `while` block inside of a `switch()` block but outside of any `case` blocks, and you can't have a `case` block inside of a `while` block.  Is the `while` block supposed to be inside the `case` block? Or the `switch()` block inside of the `while` block? Please clean up the code formatting.

Comment: /Remy Thank you. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *correct* way to handle this is to NOT draw anything on the window from inside of the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message handler at all.  That logic belongs in the `WM_PAINT` message handler instead.  Have the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler save the current line of text to a variable and then `InvalidateRect()` the window to trigger a repaint.  The `WM_PAINT` handler can then draw the current line whenever the window needs to be painted (which can happen more than once between button clicks).

Try this:

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{
    _wsetlocale(LC_ALL, L"Korean");
    ReadScn(buf); //read text from scn.txt and keep it in buf line by line.
    CharToWChar(buf, buf2); //convert char into wChar.
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE); //trigger a repaint
    return 0;
}

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    TextOut(hdc, 320, 300, buf2, lstrlen(buf2));
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank you. It works perfectly. BTW, the program prints the 5 lines of text line by line without `while`. how can that work?

Comment: If you want to display 5 lines at the same time, have `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` load the 5 lines onto separate variables, or into an array, and then have `WM_PAINT` call `TextOut` 5 times with different coordinates for each line.